# What exactly does one mean when they ask "what is your typical stack?"

Tags: php, objective-c, backend

I'm a student studying computer science. Regarding a potential internship, a company just emailed me asking "backend, whats your typical stack?"

I'm not quiet sure how to respond... I have a strong understanding of Objective-C and Cocoa APIs, but I think there asking about my web development experience. I have a decent understanding of HTML and CSS on the front end, and Python and PHP for backend.

Can someone please explain what my potential employer is asking and how I should respond? Thanks!

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: They are asking about what products you typically have used in the backend. Typical answers could range from Oracle/JBoss/Java(sprinkled with some Java EE techs) to MS SQL Server/DotNet or PostgreSQL/Python/PHP.

Comment: @JohnConde. My apologies. I'm new to this great community and I'll better before posting again.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck. Thanks for the reply. Thats what I thought, I just didn't want to reply with an inappropriate answer and appear ignorant.